# What is the intention of the  "Leere Flasche nicht verschliessen!" instruction?

Tags: meaning, translation

I have some bottles of [Hirschbraeu](http://www.hirschbraeu.de/) beer in 500ml brown bottles with swing tops like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGrolsch.jpg). On the back label, along with information about the brewery and the beer, is the instruction "Leere Flasche nicht verschliessen!"

I'd like to think I understand this sentence perfectly.  It means "Do not close the empty bottle", but that seems like a bizarre thing to put on the side of a beer bottle, especially one which appears designed to be resealable. In fact, I am planning to reuse the bottle with my own homebrewed beer. Is there something I am not getting here?

Comment: No, you're getting it right. The point is, if you _return_ the bottle to get a refund, you shouldn't close it since otherwise mold will grow inside more easily. (I guess this question should be closed as "off topic".)

Comment: ah, I forgot about the refund (we don't have that here). I don't mind if the question is closed, though I thought it would be on topic to request a translation. If it's going to stay open, if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: BTW I guess no German would speak of a 500 ml bottle. 100 ml is for drinking Wodka, we beer drinkers use '1/2-Literflaschen' or '1/3-Literflaschen'.

Comment: The question isn't bad at all, but you already gave a correct _translation_ in the question, so I thought it's not so much a _language_ question `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I don't see why it's off-topic.

Comment: @Gigili: Because the _language_ part of the answer is "you're getting it right".

Comment: The question could be considered on-topic since the OP is asking if he got the translation right. In dubio pro reo ;)

Comment: @bernd_k: I'm more familiar with 'null fünf' und 'null drei drei' for those bottles.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I've seen many questions which were asking if something is right or wrong, I recommend to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Hendrik: There is a 'close' link below the question, so just vote to close, if you think it should be closed, and yes, of course it is off topic, because it askes why the bottle should be closed, which isn't a question about german language.

Comment: @user: Well, I know, and now I have enough rep to use it, but I wasn't sure enough here to use my first ever close vote on this site. But thanks nevertheless!

Comment: I voted to reopen the question because the problem is not the question, but the misunderstanding about the question. The OP is asking about a translation, the OP provides some effort to translate the sentence. The question is not about the return-the-bottle policy, it's about the message on it. So the answers should address the translation and if they want to write a single line (as a bonus) about the policy, no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation is fine. It means *"Do not close empty bottle"*, in the sense of *sealing* the bottle.

Side note:

It refers to when you give the bottle back to the company (returnable bottle) and not when you want to re-use yourself. It does not relate to a possible security hazard (like using glass bottles in carbonating machines).

Before going back to the company the bottle should get a chance to dry, so it does not get fungi and other even less nice things in there.
Therefore it gets much more easy to clean and reusable for the company. It does not mean that if you want to re-use the bottle yourself you must not close it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and I wonder how it could get 4 up-votes. Please, reword it so it addresses the translation part of the question; the unnecessary content should be removed, or left as a "bonus"...

Comment: I had a problem because I wasn't confident in my understanding of the German message on the bottle. This and @HendrikVogt's helped me understand it, and the problem is solved.